# How to make dynamically bound AngularJS models within nested ng-repeat not throw an error until the model is supplied data from somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### The Problem

#### jsFiddle Demonstrating the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/7sfaB/

I have a situation I've run into in using AngularJS where I'm building a set of nested `<ul>` using `ng-repeat` with a nested `ng-repeat` from a config service that contains the structure of the lists. Within this nested `ng-repeat`, I am attempting to use a single complex model object by building the model dynamically based on properties within the config service and binding to an input field. (e.g. `ng-model="data[category.id][item.id].notes"`)

Here is the HTML template:

```html
<ul>
    <li id="{{category.id}}" ng-repeat="category in categoryConfig.categories">
        <h3>{{category.title}}</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in category.items">
                <p>{{item.title}} : Notes: <input type="text" ng-model="data[category.id][item.id].notes"/></p>
                <p>{{data[category.id][item.id].notes}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that if you try to edit the text field within the list, you will get `Cannot set property 'notes' of undefined` error on the console.

Interestingly, if you create an input field outside of the `ng-repeat` that has an explicit model defined to one of the same bindings that was built dynamically, then the binding starts working even within the dynamically built models.

```html
<p>
    Treasure Island Notes (dot syntax):<input type="text" ng-model="data.books.treasure_island.notes"/>
</p>
```

### The Question

What is the proper way to setup dynamically bound ng-models so that it is immediately bound and editable without having to create explicit model bindings? I wasn't sure if there was something I needed to call to make it reregister the bindings after the `ng-repeat` loops were finished.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

---

### For Reference

Here is the config service that defines the structure of the nested lists:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.factory('configSvc', function(){
    return {
        categories: [
            {
                id: 'books',
                title: 'Books',
                items:[
                    {
                        id: 'treasure_island',
                        title: 'Treasure Island'
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 'appliances',
                title: 'Household Appliances',
                items:[
                    {
                        id: 'toaster',
                        title: 'Toaster'
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

And the Controller which gets the data from the service:

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, configSvc) {

    $scope.categoryConfig = $.extend({}, configSvc);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (at least with your *Fiddle*) is that you are trying to bind to `data[category.id][item.id].notes` without either:

`$scope.data` existing or being an object

without `$scope.data[category.id]` existing or being an object

and without `$scope.data[category.id][item.id]` existing and being an object.

To solve it, after you load your data from the service, you need to loop through $scope.data and create every key you want as an object. You can do the following (verified and it works):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, configSvc) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.categoryConfig = $.extend({}, configSvc);

    angular.forEach($scope.categoryConfig.categories, function (category) {
        $scope.data[category.id] = {};
        angular.forEach(category.items, function (item) {
            $scope.data[category.id][item.id] = {};
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I was missing. I was under the assumption that because you could use things like model="someProperty" without having to declare $scope.someProperty in your controller, that those items could also be deeply created for nested objects. In otherwords, I was thinking that model="data.item.notes" would automatically create a data object with a nested item object.