# AngularJS: How do I bind data in nested ng-repeats?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, model, nested

I've got a pretty deeply nested JSON object being returned from an `$http` call, using Angular.  In my template, I have to nest a few `ng-repeats` to get present the data.  I can't seem to figure out how to bind the data using `ng-model` on a text input.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954396/how-to-make-dynamically-bound-angularjs-models-within-nested-ng-repeat-not-throw) which said that the return object isn't automatically data in the `$scope`, and you have to loop through the data and instantiate the structure.  I tried that as well with the same outcome.

```
        // Seemingly unnecessary code
        angular.forEach(Object.keys($scope.sources), function(sourcename){
            $scope.sourceData[sourcename] = {};
            angular.forEach(Object.keys($scope.sources[sourcename]), function(key){
                $scope.sourceData[sourcename][key] = $scope.sources[sourcename][key];
        });
```

Here's a fiddle showing my attempts:

http://jsfiddle.net/c7z9C/2/

I just want the values to be populated in the fields and bound to the model.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML in your example was just a little off.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5Hg9/).

The "not working" `input` just has some code in the `ng-model` that wasn't working.

First off, you don't need to interpolate `{{ }}` inside Angular directive attributes.  So, this includes `ng-model`.  So the `{{key}}` isn't necessary.

Also, `sourceData` was misspelled.  It was supposed to be `sourcedata` and case matters.

So the end result for the `ng-model` is `ng-model="sourcedata[key]"`:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in sourcedata">
        WORKS: <input type="text" value="{{value}}" /><br/>
        DOESN'T: <input type="text" ng-model="sourcedata[key]" />
    </li>
```

Comment: First thank you very much, these points are really helpful. This is indeed the correct answer here.  Sorry for the typos, I was cobbling together a Fiddle from much more complicated code and I mistyped. Finally, your answer made me realize that I didn't accurately represent my full problem.  I was trying to do ng-model="sources[sourcename][key]" because I wanted to use the $scope.sources data.  I'll try that now... finger's crossed!

Comment: For posterity, ng-model="sources[sourcename][key]" worked perfectly.